# Django admin sessions: change default value

Tags: python, django, django-admin

How can I change the default expiration time value for the session in Django admin? what is the function to override?

Thanks.

Comment: you need it in django admin only ?

Comment: Yes, I would add only one expiration time value for all accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 5 * 60
```

This is for every user and also independent of whether user is active or inactive.

Answer (score 0):

Djangos `set_expiry` is used to set expiration time for a session.

You can read about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.set_expiry).

You usually will set it before logging in the User:

```
...
request.session.set_expiry(300)
login(request, user)
...
```